# MIPs Instruction Set Latency (in cycles) and Pseudo Instruction

Tags: mips

I've been looking for a reference table/table sheet with all MIPs instruction set latency (in clock cycles) and couldn't find it anywhere, just a few instructions here and there... like "add: 1 cycle, load word: 5 cycles, ...". Does anyone has a reference for these instructions (in MIPs) with their latency?

Also, I'm searching for pseudo-instructions translations and their real implementations! I've found a bit of it in the book "Computer Organization and Design; Patterson".

Comment: Latency is not really a property of an instruction set, but rather an implementation of the ISA, which you haven't specified.  There are dozens of MIPS implementations, ranging from single cycle, to multi-cycle, to pipelined where there is R2000, R3000, R10000, various versions of MIPS32, etc..  This ISA at least 30 years old and has had many implementations over the years, each generation with different latencies.

Comment: Pseudo instructions are just convenience, so we should interpret latency by looking to  their translation into real instructions.